# Setting control Enabled property in SelectedIndexChanged() only works first time it is run

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdown and I want to change another controls Enabled property when a certain value is chosen, e.g

```
private void ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged()
{

 if (ddlTest.Value == "1")
        {
            TextBox1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox1.Enabled = true;
        }
}
```

This works the first time it is run but never again after that - am I missing something?

Comment: Each time you change the list index, it will do a round-trip to the server.  Would you be willing to consider a JavaScript solution instead?

Comment: In your Page_Load, are you are you setting the available values in the DropDownList?  If so, did you wrap that code in a ```if (!IsPostBack)``` block?  If not, it will wipe out all entries and reinsert them every post-back, and any selected value you had will be lost.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming you meant ddlTest.SelectedValue, since .Value isn't a property of a DropDownList.